# How do I open a page in ibox with javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm using ibox.js taken from web http://www.enthropia.com/labs/ibox/download.php.

I'd like to open a page to the ibox with javascript.

```
$j(".refresh").click(function() {
    $j('#case_01').attr('rel': 'ibox', 'href': 'case_01.html);
});
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

if you use jquery [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) 
,try this

```
$(".refresh").click(function() {
         //$j('#case_01').attr('rel': 'ibox', 'href': 'case_01.html);
          $('#case_01').attr('rel','ibox').attr('href','case_01.html');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set multiple attrbiutes using object literal syntax. Currently is not set correctly and you have a typo.

This should work:

```
$j(".refresh").click(function() {
    $j('#case_01').attr({rel: 'ibox', href: 'case_01.html'});
});
```

Note:

> " When setting multiple attributes, the quotes around attribute names
>   are optional.
>
> WARNING: When setting the 'class' attribute, you must always use
>   quotes!
>
> jQuery prohibits changing the type attribute on an or element and will
>   throw an error in all browsers. This is because the type attribute
>   cannot be changed in Internet Explorer. "